# Getting pointer to C string containing hex values

Tags: c++, c-strings

I had such code

```
char *p = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
      printf(" %d ", *(p + i));
```

But the output was -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1, which is not what I want. I wanted
255 255 255 255 255 255.

So, I modified above code like this:

```
unsigned char *p = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
      printf(" %d ", *(p + i));
```

But was getting error: "a value of type `"const char *"` cannot be used to initialize an entity of type `"unsigned char *"`

Finally, I modified it like this and it works.

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*) "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
      printf(" %d ", *(p + i));
```

I think this is a fine modification, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
  printf(" %u ", (unsigned char)(*(p + i)));
```

To print.

Comment: without the modification I described, it still doesn't seem to work this way, but thanks for input

Comment: @user2568508 That's why, when posting a question, you should always mark the line on which an error occurs. It seems dbasic thought the problem was in the `printf`.

Comment: @user2568508 `char *p = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";` works fine (but more correctly is `char const * p`. See http://ideone.com/auyBJ7

Comment: @RedX: yes initially I thought 255 didn't fit inside char...(since it printed -1)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use numbers when printing numbers and strings when printing strings. So:

```
unsigned char p[6];
memset(p, 0xFF, 6);
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
  printf(" %d ", p[i]);
```

Edit: Just to know. If the most significant bit is 1 then it is negative, if you declair char   or int or short so `255 = 0b**1**1111111` negative

valter

Comment: This I know I just wanted to initialize using a C string

Comment: You are totaly right. But i wasn't familiar with this `"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"` kind of string.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the string literal `"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"` is `const char*`. Without having to use dirty casting to non-const type you should declare `p` as `const`:

```
const char *p = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";
```

If you then want to output as unsigned values, cast the values in your output line.

```
for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    printf(" %u ", (unsigned char)(*(p + i)));
```

Background: The literal is safed in a possibly read-only area of your memory (while this is not the fact on usual pc systems, where the memory is writable). You should yet not depend on the memory to be writeable and if you don't so, you may declare the data `const`.

Comment: initially I thought 255 didn't fit inside char...(since it printed -1), it seems it just interpreted 255 as signed.. ?

Comment: No, it interprets the bit-chain 11111111 as -1 (since the sign bit is the first one).

Comment: Yes it seems it interpreted "11111111" as -1..., but why?

Comment: Because 11111111 is the two's complement representation of -1 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: yes yes I know, but it is 255 also, so it could have interpereted "11111111" as 255 too right? why it chose -1? it seems it has to do that it was of char type

Comment: because the type is signed and the signed value ranges from -128 to 127 only.

Comment: hm... I see. So initially I said more or less 'correctly' when I referred in above comments that I thought 255 didn't fit inside char ...ps. yes I know "11111111" is -1 in binary/2's complement.